# WCF. Use windows credentials on service side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have client on WPF and service. It's worked with security mode=None. But now I need on service side Windows credentials of the user who call service for making some action on Azure. So I changed configuration and now it's the following:

**Service**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<client />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TrackingHoursServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="620000">
     <!-- WAS THIS 
    <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security> -->

    <!-- This is my changes  -->
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    <!-- This my changes  -->
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPortableService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.TrackingHoursServiceBehavior" name="AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.TrackingHoursService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TrackingHoursServiceBinding" contract="AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.ITrackingHoursService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="pcl" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPortableService" contract="AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.ITrackingHoursService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.TrackingHoursServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="connectionStatusBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="serviceRegistrySettings" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="httpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="httpsRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="onewayRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="webHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netEventRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TrackingHoursServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="False">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <!-- WAS 
     <security mode="None" /> 
     -->
     <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITFSService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://AAA/TrackingHoursService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TrackingHoursServiceBinding" contract="ITrackingHoursService" name="WSHttpBinding_ITrackingHoursService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://2121212/WSELFO/TFSService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITFSService" contract="ITFSService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITFSService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

On the service side, i try take credential using

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

or

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

But they return empty object.... How i can solve this issue?

Comment: To use windows authentication, you need to add windows credentials when calling: calculatorClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Administrator";      calculatorClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";

Comment: @Ding Peng but I thought it should automatically send the credentials of the user who calls this service

Comment: What the client needs to provide when calling the server is the windows credentials of the server.

Comment: @Ding Peng but i don't want to do it manually. i try send credentials of the user who use client.

Comment: @Ding Peng
i try tcs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
but in service 
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
and 
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
it still empty

Comment: The credentials returned by the DefaultNetworkCredentials property and the DefaultCredentials property are only applicable to NTLM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221255/discussion-between---and-ding-peng).

Answer (score 0):

After my test, I found that System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials does not return null, whether on the client or server. Do you want to obtain username, password or domain through System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials? If this is the case, it will return null because the instance DefaultCredentials returned by ICredentials cannot be used to view the user name, password, or domain of the current security context.

[image]

Comment: No, i don't need user name and password. on service side i want create WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(Uri baseUrl, VssCredentials credentials). VssCredentials  i can create using windows credentials. so i whant pass user credentials to VssCredentials constructor. But when i use  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials in service yes seems it not empty, but seems also that it doesn't contain user credentials which call service. Probably, it takes some default credentials

Comment: ehhh. idk. i change wsHttpBinding to basicHttBinding security mode = TransportCredentialOnly, transport = NTLM. in IIS settings Enabled Anonymous and windows Authentication. its works partial from OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name i see ny user, but System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials return credentials of domain\computername$. and if i disable Anonymous Authentication in iis it does not work at all

Comment: DefaultCredentials represents the system credentials of the current security context of the running application. For client applications, these are usually the Windows credentials of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user or the impersonated user.